# MySQL select points which are contained in a polygon from a different table

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial

I have two tables.

Table a contains a list of names and locations (points)
Table b contains a list of names and shape (polygons)

I want to write a query to find all points from a which are contained inside a given town from b

Something along the lines of

```
select name from tblshops where st_contains(select shape from tbltowns where name="London", location)
```

but I keep getting a syntax error. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Ok, solved it. What worked for me was set @var= (select shape from tbltowns where name="London"); and then use it in st_contains. i.e. select name from tblshops where st_contains(@var, location); Quite annoyed I can't delete the question or answer it because my reputation is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   name 
FROM 
   tblshops
WHERE 
   st_contains((select shape from tbltowns where name='London'), location)
```

Comment: this answer contains only one argument?

Comment: @user3364894 : provide you exact tables' ddl (structure)

Comment: Ok, solved it. What worked for me was set @var= (select shape from tbltowns where name="London"); and then use it in st_contains. i.e. select name from tblshops where st_contains(@var, location);

Comment: @user3364894 : You can just use the code above without setting extra variables.

Comment: oh I see. I didn't use the brackets. Thanks